# Process form according to chosen option on alert box

Tags: javascript

I'd like to modify the way some of my edit forms work...on submitting the form, the user is prompted with an aler box.  If he/she chooses "Yes" then the record will be edited...on choosing "Cancel" however, the record will be saved as a new record.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your "alert box", which allows your user to choose between "Yes / No", is actually using the `confirm()` function ?

If so, `confirm()` will return a truthy or falsy value, depending on what the user choosed.

Which means you could use something like this :

```
if (confirm("Do you want to save ?")) {
    // save
} else {
    // do not save
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No — since alert boxes only have one button :)

You could do this with a `confirm`, doing something like:

```
myForm.onsubmit = function () {
    if (confirm('Foo?')) { 
        this.elements.record.value = "edit";
    }
}
```

and

```
<input type="hidden" name="record" value="new">
```

However, this violates [rule one](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build) and you would be better off just having:

```
<input type="radio" name="record" value="new" id="record_new">
<label for="record_new">New record/label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="record" value="edit" id="record_edit" checked>
<label for="record_edit">Edit existing record/label>
```